# Desktop environment menu missing on 12.10

Tags: 12.10, login, desktop-environments

I am using ubuntu 12.10 and when I go to the login screen it doesn't have the desktop environment menu. There is no button for the menu which is really annoying because I want to change environment.

Comment: Please list all the environments you have installed on your system.

Comment: Maybe you deleted LightDM.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried clicking on the Ubuntu icon in the username/password box?

[image: the ubuntu icon, in the upper right corner]

Clicking on it should reveal a list of the environments you have on your system:

[image]